# Builds do not start on gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have installed gitlab and gitlab_ci (with runners) on the same server running CentOS 6.5. Problem: Builds to not start.

Both gitlab and gitlab_ci pages render fine. I have "checked" things several times (i.e., redis, the ports, iptables, fully disabled selinux, and ran "bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production" as the git user for sanity sake), but the builds do not start. I verified the project settings on gitlab -> project -> settings -> services ... and everything checks out.

Is there anything that I'm missing? Is the above setup actually an acceptable setup?

Thanks!
J